# Chain function calls which return error codes or 0 on success in C

Tags: c, coding-style, code-reviews, error-handling

I used to call functions which returns `int` error code or `0` on success like this:

```c
int tmp = function_a() ?:
          function_b() ?:
          function_c();

if (tmp)
        handle_error();
```

Now I'm working on a project which `-std=c90 -Wpedantic` and I get:

```
warning: ISO C forbids omitting the middle term of a ?: expression [-Wpedantic]
```

Is there any good `ISO C` approach for this? I want to avoid this:

```
int tmp;

tmp = function_a();

if (tmp)
        handle_error();

tmp = function_b();

if (tmp)
        handle_error();
```

And this:

```
int tmp;

if ((tmp = function_a()))
       handle_error();
```

And mangling code with `#define` macros.

Comment: Why are you using `?:` in the first place? As long as you're using error return codes as booleans, you can just chain things with `&&` or `||`:  `int error_code = a() || b() || c();`

Comment: @KilianFoth I can not. I want to know the error code.

Comment: You should add that bit of information to the question.  I was also going to suggest an approach that threw away the error code...

Comment: What are you talking about? Since `0` signals success, composing calls with `||` *does* give you the error code.

Comment: @KilianFoth Expression `-2 || 0` will evaluate to `1` (I know that error occured, but I don't know what error). Expression `-2 ?: 0` will evaluate to `-2`. That's the difference.

Comment: @PiotrJedyk My mistake, I misremembered the coercion rules.  It only works if you use `|` rather than `||`.

Comment: Please don't do any of this. Just do it the if-handle error way. Every other way suggested here will discourage proper error reporting later on and hurts debuggability.

Answer (score 3):

While you could use a temporary variable to save the result, you'd end up with something like:

```
int tmp;
tmp = (tmp = function_a()) ? tmp : ((tmp = function_b()) ? tmp : function_c());
```

Needless to say, don't do this.  It is the equivalent of your old code, but is far less elegant.  Even if it is more verbose, you should simply go with the more readable solution:

```
int tmp;
if(tmp = function_a()) {
    handle_error(tmp);
} else if (tmp = function_b()) {
    handle_error(tmp);
} else if (tmp = function_c()) {
    handle_error(tmp);
}
```

You could also write it like this, which perhaps would be a little more straightforward:

```
int tmp;
if((tmp = function_a()) || (tmp = function_b()) || (tmp = function_c())) {
    handle_error(tmp);
}
```

Comment: It's OK. But the first non-standard way is still most readable I think...

Comment: @PiotrJedyk why? You've got a chained assignment to the same name. `tmp = tmp = function_a()` sounds like something a politician would say